# Valgrind: Conflicting load by thread in getter method which contains a rdlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, valgrind

I have a common getter method with rdlock and unlock:

```
e_state get_state   ( )
{
    rdlock();
    e_state state= m_e_state;
    unlock();
    return state;
}
```

The setter with writelock and unlock:

```
void set_state (e_state a_new_e_state)  
{
    wrlock();
    m_e_state = a_new_e_state;
    unlock();
}
```

The rdlock(), wrlock() and unlock() methods are the followings:

```
bool rdlock ( ){return pthread_rwlock_rdlock (&m_rwlock) == 0;}
bool wrlock ( ){return pthread_rwlock_wrlock (&m_rwlock) == 0;}
bool unlock ( ){return pthread_rwlock_unlock (&m_rwlock) == 0;}
```

With Valgrind I got the following errors:

```
Conflicting load by thread 3 at 0x04328fa0 size 4
==16557==    at 0x8068712: Sample_Namespace::get_state() (CClassManagerXY.h:94)
==16557==    by 0x807FA9B: Sample_Namespace::xy_method(std::string const&,                          Sample_Namespace::IClassX&, int) (IClassY.cpp:773)
==16557==    by 0x48CC8CA: Sources::SourceClassX::run() (SourceClassX.cpp:156)
==16557==    by 0x8065BEF: run(void*) (CClassManagerXY.cpp:120)
==16557==    by 0x402A31B: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-x86-linux.so)
==16557==    by 0x4062B24: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.11.2.so)
==16557==    by 0x428446D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.11.2.so)
==16557== Address 0x4328fa0 is at offset 8 from 0x4328f98. Allocation context:
==16557==    at 0x4029BD3: operator new(unsigned int) (in       /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-x86-linux.so)
==16557==    by 0x807E9FD: Sample_Namespace::loads(std::string const&, bool)    (CClassY.cpp:460)
==16557==    by 0x807EE9A: Sample_Namespace::load() (CClassY.cpp:542)
==16557==    by 0x807D7D4: Sample_Namespace::init() (CClassY.cpp:171)
==16557==    by 0x808D57C: main (main.cpp:203)
==16557== Other segment start (thread 2)
==16557==    at 0x4284458: clone (in /lib/libc-2.11.2.so)
==16557== Other segment end (thread 2)
==16557==    at 0x42925E6: __lll_unlock_wake_private (in /lib/libc-2.11.2.so)
==16557==    by 0x41F45DD: _L_unlock_13308 (in /lib/libc-2.11.2.so)
==16557==    by 0x41F4527: buffered_vfprintf (in /lib/libc-2.11.2.so)
==16557==    by 0x41EF2FA: vfprintf (in /lib/libc-2.11.2.so)
==16557==    by 0x41F9BAE: fprintf (in /lib/libc-2.11.2.so)
==16557==    by 0x40395F7: Sample_Namespace::write_trace_record(int, unsigned int, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...) (CTrace.cpp:106)
==16557==    by 0x8065C84: run_adapter(void*) (CClassManagerXY.cpp:124)
==16557==    by 0x402A31B: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-x86-linux.so)
==16557==    by 0x4062B24: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.11.2.so)
==16557==    by 0x428446D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.11.2.so)
```

I don't know why can Data Race be near the state variable, I managed there the locks. I dont understand well what is the meaning of the "Address is at offset 8 from..." row. Have you got any tip what is the problem?

Comment: It would be useful to know what you do at the other segments. `wirte_trace_record` somewhat looks like you write out the value of m_e_state without locking, which will of course cause drd to complain.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. The write_trace_record not use the m_e_state variable or the get_state method. However there is a set_state(running) method in the run_adapter method where the write_trace_record call is, but with set the m_e_state via the setter method I dont avoid the wrlock(). The run_adapter and the get/set_state methods are in the same class of course.

Comment: In the valgrind trace there are some rows started by REDIR. I don't know what is means

Comment: Maybe you can reduce this to some testcase (the fewer lines the better) that reproduces the same problem to see what is going on. I still think that the conflict V talks about is based on the access there, which it finds is not coherently locked with the position it reported. You might watn to output the addresses of the locks locked whenever you access the mentioned memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You PlasmaHH!
I have found there are one more method use the variable. It was my mistake. 
However I don't understand well, is conflicting load really dangerous? Not only conflicting store?